# What video player does html5 use?

Tags: html, video

Suppose I use the `<video>` tag to include some video in my webpage. When a client visits this page, the video is played:

1) By his browser. So even if his computer has installed no programs like Window Media Player, the video still plays.

2) By a default program chosen by his OS, but somehow this program is now embedded in the browser UI. For example, if the OS use WMP to play `.mp4` video, now the browser is also using WMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 video player does no longer use a plugin for video playback like you used to do.

Instead there is a video standard defined in the html5 specs [W3.org - html5 - video](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element)

It is up to the browser makers to correctly implement these standards in their browser and therefor to implement a videoplayer.